# plsql - cursor to see if a record already exists

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Using a pl sql procedure to insert from a temporary table into separate tables
how do I check if a record is duplicated by using an if statement

1. if it doesnt exist then insert
2. if does exist then show the duplicate in a message (dbms_output.put_line) and continue in the loop with the other records

temp table:

```
create table temp_table
(job title varchar2(20)
,empname varchar2(30));
```

i have a job table with `job_id`, `job_title` 
i have an employee table with `empid`, `empname`, `jobid`

Comment: The simplest approach might be to just outer-join the two tables, then you'll know which rows matched and which didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The PLSQL block which you want is as below.

***Tables:***

```
CREATE  TABLE temp_table (
job_title  VARCHAR2(20),
empname varchar2(30));

--------------------------

CREATE  TABLE job (
job_id number,
job_title  VARCHAR2(20));

------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE emplyee (
empid number, 
empname varchar2(30),
job_id number
);

------------------------------
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ( 'Dan', 'Morgan');
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ( 'Helen', 'Lofstrom');
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ( 'Akiko', 'Toyota' );
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ( 'Jackie', 'Stough');
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ( 'Richard', 'Foote');
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ( 'Joe', 'Johnson');
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ( 'Clark', 'Urling');

-------------------------
create  sequence seq_id start with 1 increment by 1 nocycle;
-----------------
```

***PL SQL Block***

```
  declare

     dummy integer;
     jb_id number;
     ep_id  number;
     job_cntr number:=0;
     emp_cntr number:=0;
    begin

    for rec in (select * from temp_table)
     loop

        jb_id:= seq_id.nextval*101;
        ep_id:= seq_id.nextval;
       ---Test if row exists before inserting
        select count(*) 
        into dummy
        from  job jb
        where jb.job_title = rec.job_title;

        if dummy = 0 then     
         insert into  job(job_id,job_title) values (jb_id,rec.job_title);
        else     
         --dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate record in Job table.!!! Records Exis-'||rec.job_title);
          job_cntr:=job_cntr + 1 ;
        end if;     

      ---Test if row exists before inserting
        select count(*) 
        into dummy
        from  emplyee emp
        where emp.empname = rec.empname;

        if dummy = 0 then     
         insert into  emplyee(empid,empname,job_id) values (ep_id,rec.empname,jb_id);
         else     
         --dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate record in Employee..!!! Records Exis-'||rec.empname);
          emp_cntr := emp_cntr + 1;
        end if;

     end loop;

      commit;

      dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate record in Job table-'||job_cntr || ' Duplicate record in Employee.' ||emp_cntr );

    end;
--
```

***Test:***

```
select * from job;
select * from emplyee;
```

Comment: Thanks you, a great help!..... what if we had 2 records of 'Dan','Morgan' is there a way that we can record this ?? to show that these are duplicated

Comment: We can raise an exception and handle it

Comment: You can use this exception DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX but then your table should have a primary key

Comment: Yes..it's possible. ..Google down..you will find many examples.

Comment: I have created a dup_val_on_index exception but this only catches either the empname or job_title that are duplicated, is there a way we can capture if the both are the same

Comment: Can paste your code and edit your question for better understanding.

Comment: Yes so this is the procedure I have created:

Comment: create or replace procedure version2 
as
p_jobid number; 
cursor cursor_staging is 
select * from temp_table; 
begin

for rec in cursor_staging loop 

begin 

insert_job(p_jobid,rec.job_title); 
 
exception when dup_val_on_index then 
dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate Job: ' || rec.job_title); 
null; 
end;

begin 
insert_emp(rec.empname,p_jobid); 

exception when dup_val_on_index then 
dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate EmpName: ' || rec.empname);
null;
end;

end loop;
end;

Comment: if I have 2 duplicates of both empname and job_title I want to show this, as the way I have it now, it records duplicates of just job_title or just empname. I need it to be only in the case of when both are the same

Comment: Whats the problem when you run the above block.. Are you not getting messages. Above code will show you the name and job title as wel

Comment: Say I have in my temp_table, 2 values of 'HR' as the job_title but they have different empname values of 'Dan' and 'John',, the messages will return  2 messages of 'Duplicate Job: HR' but what I what is to show a message ONLY when there are 2 or more values of say 'HR' as job_title AND the mulitple values of the same empname say of 'Dan'  -- i hope this is more clear, thank you for the help

Comment: And you want this from which table..You have now 3 tables..job,employee and temp_table.

Comment: The above will give you the count of duplicates in a single row

Comment: from the temp_table, the loop will go through each row by row so I want it to log a message of the ones that are duplicates of both the same job_title and empname

Comment: If you want to dispaly those in a single row it would be difficult to understand the log. Also its not possible to caputre exception getting raised from 2 sql to a single statement. you can run my block and see if this works for you